# Maclaurin series of $c= c_0 (\lvert \frac{w}{w_0} \rvert)^{\frac{1}{\pi Q}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I don't understand a passage found in a file

given the  relation
$$c \sim c_0 \bigg \lvert \frac{w}{w_0}\bigg\rvert^{\frac{1}{\pi Q}} $$
the author says that the first 2 terms of the Maclaurin  series expansion may be written as

$$\frac{c}{c_0}= 1 + \frac{1}{\pi Q}  \ln{\bigg \lvert \frac{w}{w_0}\bigg\rvert}+ \dots $$

but if I put $w=0$ to compute the first term I get 0, not 1. Furthermore I don't get from where the logarithm should came from in the second term.

Comment: Write $$\bigg \lvert \frac{w}{w_0}\bigg\rvert^{\frac{1}{\pi Q}} = \exp\left(    \frac{1}{\pi Q}\log  \bigg \lvert \frac{w}{w_0}\bigg\rvert \right)$$ and use $\exp(z)= 1+z+\ldots$ This is useful when $w\approx w_0$ and not near $0$.